# Landsat composite band issue

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, landsat

I am new to remote sensing. I downloaded a landsat image from earth explorer. It was in tar.gz format. I used 7-zip to extract the files. I got 7 tiff images and 1 jpg image.

I added those 7 images in arc map 10.4.1 and made a composite layer. I made it permanent as the one generated first is always a temp file. But i found that （both temp as well as ）the permanent file has only band 1 mentioned in front of red green and blue.

When I try to change the band numbers I get 7 bands all of which are numbered as 1. Although I can still make it an fcc image by clicking on the fourth, third and the second band in the layers window corresponding to red green and blue bands respectively.

But why the bands are not numbered from 1 to 7?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to work on FCC only, then its quite a simple task. See which Landsat data you have downloaded, according to which you can get to know what band corresponds to which wavelength and what is its best usage. [Landsat bands specifications](http://landsat.usgs.gov/best_spectral_bands_to_use.php). After that take only those bands (maybe Red, NIR and Green) which show your required elements of interest. The order of bands which will be shown in properties window would be Green, Red and NIR. Now you can tweak the RGB bands to work for you.